# Installing Error during ap Installation on other device

Tags: java, installation, android-studio-3.0

My app is running successfully on my android device which is installed during build  but when I send this app to another device via bluetooth/whatsapp  from my device it does't run on this device show App not installed error....any body can help plz

Answer (score 0):

The device does not support the function app needs like camera, wifi, or SDK version.

You might want to check the requirement of the app in there page.